# Bug using deleteDataBase() method

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm using the "context.deleteDatabase("***");" to remove the sqlite database from my aplication. i delete an recreate the database.
The problem is that I have to restart the application to see the new database. 
Do I have to make some "commit changes" to refresh the databese?

Comment: I am not aware that it supports wildcards. Beyond that, what do you mean by that you "have to restart the aplication to see the changes"?

Comment: When I delete the database, I have to restart the application to see the new database.

Comment: Well, what are you doing otherwise to force the database to actually recreate? Did you `close()` your `SQLiteOpenHelper` before deleting the database? Did you then call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()` on the `SQLiteOpenHelper` after deleting the database?

Comment: I did call close before to delete and I call getWritableDatabase() after delete to recreate the database.

Comment: What means are you using to determine that you "have to restart the application to see the new database"? Have you added breakpoints or logging to confirm that your `onCreate()` of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` is being called when you expect?

Comment: I used. The onCreate is called only when I restart the application. Before a restart the app, the database remains the same old.

Comment: Try creating a new instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` after deleting the database, if you have not tried that yet.

Comment: I tried this. Did not work. I have to close and open the app to see the new database.

Comment: I have this exact same issue in 2022. Seems like context.deleteDatabase("mydatabase"); not happens immediately after the call. Instead it wipes out the data randomly, which is a big problem, because sometimes - while using the application - the datas are suddenly missing . Does anybody here have solution for this?